# How to get JSON or XML from parsed Ext js Tree?

Tags: xml, json, extjs, tree, treepanel

I have Tree, loaded from XML exactly like [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/tree/xml-tree-loader.html).

Additionally I enable drag and drop.
Now after making changes in tree by drag and drop, we should be able to get new data so that I can generate new xml.

Even JSON would help to re-generate new xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getJson(treeNode) {
    treeNode.expandChildNodes();
    var json = {};
    var attributes = treeNode.attributes;
    for(var item in attributes){
        if (item == 'src' || item == 'text') {   //only use required attributes
            json[item] = attributes[item];
        }
    }
    json.children = [];
    if(treeNode.childNodes.length > 0){
        for (var i=0; i < treeNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
            json.children.push(getJson(treeNode.childNodes[i]));
        }
    }
    return json;
}

// To use above function:
var comp = Ext.getCmp('tree-panel'); //id of the tree panel
var myJSON = getJson(comp.getRootNode());
console.log(Ext.encode(myJSON.children));
```

Can't think about creating XML. I'll make it on server side..

Hope someone could also work on it.